# Why isn't my Bootstrap modal window working in Opera?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, opera

I have a modal login window set up using the Twitter Bootstrap framework, exactly as described at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals (using the Markup method and using their demo modal window as a starting point).
It works wonderfully on multiple browsers (which is one of the great reasons to use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) in the first place).

However, when I test my page in Opera, the modal window is not working. The page fades out like it should, but the window does not appear. Why?

Using: Bootstrap v2.0.4, Opera 12

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3876) in Bootstrap, and I'm sure a fix is in the works, but for those of you who can't wait, or can't just change framework versions willy-nilly, here's a nice fix:
The problem is due to the "fade" class used in the typical markup for the modal window:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in">
```

This `fade` class provides the nice animation for the appearance/dismissal of the modal window. And it's apparently broken in Opera 12.

While removing the `fade` class will make it work, there's no reason to deprive other browser users, so you can utilize this handy snippet of Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        if (navigator.appName == "Opera")
        {
            $('#myModal').removeClass('fade');
        }
    });
</script>
```

This will remove the `fade` class for Opera, but retain it for other browsers. Note that this will disable it for Opera altogether, including people on older versions. If you're interested in narrowing the scope of the fix, you can test `navigator.userAgent` to determine the version (the User Agent header for Opera 12 is `Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.00` on my computer, but since that won't be universal you'd just want to check for the presence of the `12.00` at the end of the string. Maybe someone industrious and less sleepy can add a souped up version in the comments :)

Comment: Since it's still not fixed in 12.01, you can use: `if (navigator.appName == "Opera" && navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/12\./)) {`

Comment: simpler and global:
`if ($.browser.opera) $('.fade').removeClass('fade');`
(when DOM is ready of course)

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest using modernizr and something like 
`$('.no-csstransforms3d .fade').removeClass('fade');` 
rather

that way if for instance opera release opera 13 the code above wont work :P

could do `.no-csstransforms3d .modal.fade`

Comment: This is an excellent and useful, though unless they're already using Modernizr, it's probably just as easy to update to a working fork of Bootstrap. My method is aimed at people who (like me) are more hamstrung in terms of what libraries we can use and update in a given project. But bonus knowledge is always ++ :)

Comment: te problemo is what happens when opera suddenly release 3d transforms.. then you have to edit your code again.. im pretty sure they might just add it to 12.50 (not in yet tho). i have the latest git repo for bootstrap.. still doesnt work without the above "fix" in opera next

Comment: keep in mind as well that google+ wasnt working with opera 12.50 when it first came out.. the fix was to change your browser string to mirror firefox etc.. so if any user that has done so tries bootstrap... problems

i really think all projects should include modernizr hehe :P it makes developing soooooooo much easier

Comment: I certainly agree, Modernizr is a godsend and I'm already using it many places throughout my site. Back when I researched it, though, I couldn't determine what was failing (i.e. what compatibility to test with Modernizr) so I went for more of a shotgun approach. But your info is great, thanks